# Adding hash tag to URL messed up CSS on page

Tags: html, css, muse

I'm having the most bizarre issue. 
When you navigate to this page on my site on desktop (greater than 1200px) without hash tags, everything looks great:

http://smartcookie.media/ttec/services.html

But when hashtags are added, the page gets messed up.  I have no idea why and I am using Adobe Muse, unfortunately(I did not create the code).

http://smartcookie.media/ttec/services.html#professionalsvs

The element #page seems to push to the left.

Can anyone help me figure out what is the issue?

Thanks!
David

Comment: I changed to a scrollto approach,which works on a desktop, but on iphone, the offset().top position always returns 0: 

http://smartcookie.media/ttec/services.html?anchor=managesvs

I searched for an answer but could not find one. Does anyone have any idea of how to fix this?

Thanks, David